# How to bring duplicate rows based on given condition

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows

```
create table t (
  invoice_no int,
  serial_no text,
  price decimal(10,2));

insert into t values
(1001, 'XYZ123', 20),
(1002, 'XYZ123', 20),
(1003, 'XYZ456', 24),
(1004, 'XYZ456', 24),
(1005, 'ABC109', 15),
(1006, 'BGF108', 15),
(1006, 'ABC107', 10),
(1006, 'ABC104', 10);
```

An invoice can have multiple serial numbers. (i.e. A bill with multiple products on it)

I need to find the invoices where serial numbers appear in more than one invoice.  Then I need to find out those invoices and serial numbers. Otherwise I need the query to return zero records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.serial_no = t.serial_no AND t1.Invoice_no <> t.Invoice_no);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
select serial_no
from tablename
group by serial_no
having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

> if same serial numbers are appeared in multiple invoices then i need to find out those invoices and serial numbers.

You can do this with `group by` and `array_agg()`:

```
select serial_no, array_agg(invoice_no)
from t
group by serial_no
having count(*) >= 2;
```

If you want the actual rows, then you can use `exists` (as suggested by Yogesh).

Answer (score 0):

To find duplicate serial numbers, use `count` and `group by`

```
select serial_no
from t
group by serial_no
having count(*) >= 2
```

and to get the invoices with corresponding serial numbers

```
select invoice_no, serial_no
from t
where serial_no in (select serial_no
                    from t
                    group by serial_no
                    having count(*) >= 2);
```

See [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0aeeca/9/0)

Answer (score 0):

use `STRING_AGG()` analytic function

```
select serial_no, STRING_AGG(invoice_no)
from t
group by serial_no
having count(*) >1;
```